# Why isn't every loop homotopic to the constant loop?

Tags: general-topology

Isn't $H_s(t) = \alpha((1 - s)t)$ a homotopy between the constant loop $c(t) = \alpha(0)$ and $\alpha$?

Comment: In what space?$ $

Comment: @Arthur some arbitrary topological space where `\alpha` is a loop in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s an **unbased** homotopy. You have just observed that $I$ is a contractible space.

But in the fundamental group we care about the **based** homotopy classes, and $H_s(1)=\alpha((1-s))$ need not equal $H_s(0)=\alpha(0)$ in general. So this might not be a *based* homotopy of loops a.k.a a *loop* homotopy.

Comment: thanks, I didn't read the definition properly!

Answer (score 0):

Because in homotopy theory (in particular when talking about the fundamental group) you want all the $H_s$ to also be loops. Sure, what you have are homotopies between the two paths, but there is no reason for $H_{1/2}$ to be a loop.